# Using Node's request module to upload files via REST API

Tags: node.js

I am using the request module for communicating with the rest API.

So far everything was perfect, and now I have problems with uploading files.

This is my code:

```
    var url = "www.targetsite.com";
    var options = {
        method: 'post',
        json: true,
        body: {
            parameter: 'param'
        },
        formData: {
            file: fs.createReadStream("pic.jpg");
        }
    }

    request(url, options, function(err, res, res_body){
         console.log(err);
         ...
    }
```

Here I receive the error **Error: write after end**

If I then remove the "json" and "body" from the options, it makes the request, and returns the error from the other side (missing parameter).

So, how can I send both "body" and upload file in the same call?

Comment: The content type can be only 1, you're tryin to pass 2 types, `application/json, multipart/form-data`, convert the body params to form data

Comment: @Medet, Thank you, that worked!
Can you please post this as an answer in order to accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thi should work pretty well

```
var url = "www.targetsite.com";
var options = {
    parameter: 'param',
    file: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/pic.jpg")
}

request.post({url: url, formData: options}, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
  // done
});
```